# ajax success call appears in firebug, but not on screen

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to get a output.The response appears on the firebug panel. But not on my browser.

Here is the form I am using.

```
<LABEL for="test">
    Party Name
    <input type  id='test' name="test" class=".test" />   
</LABEL>
```

Ajax success call

```
success: function (html) 
{ 
    $("#test").append(html); 
}


<select  name="plid" id="plid">
    <option value="" selected="selected">--Select the Pack Name--</option>
    <option value='A TO Z PHARMACY'>A TO Z PHARMACY</option>
    <option value='A.A.HOMOEO HALL'>A.A.HOMOEO HALL</option>
    <option value='A.A.HOMOEO HALL (ROBRA)'>A.A.HOMOEO HALL (ROBRA)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: class=".test" this is wrong class="test"

Comment: `class=".test"` is valid

Comment: @SamithaHewawasam.. Class is a http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-class

Answer (score 4):

use `.val()` to set data in `input`

```
$("#test").val(html);
```

- http://api.jquery.com/val/

**Edit:**

If you want to append the html after the text input, you can do this -

```
$(html).insertAfter('#test');
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/8uSWP/1/

Comment: Does label take `val()`? Thought it was text? I could be wrong

Comment: Yup you're right...read the code too fast and saw the closing label tag, +1

Comment: Actually this form is ajax rendered one(from another page), I am trying to insert a selectbox inside that form.. Could that be problem?@pXL Thanks for replyin

Comment: @user2234992 -- What is the data that comes back?

Comment: @user2234992 `$(html).insertAfter('#test');`

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you were asking in the comments above with pXL, if the `select` you're returning is already formatted, EX:

```
<select>
    <option>Stuff</option>
    ..more options
</select>
```

Then you can do this:

```
$("#test").after(html);
```

This will append the `select` after the input with ID `test`

Comment: Could you post your output of `console.log(html)` (use this in the success function)